# How to change detail stack error (UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: servicestack

When i used `[Restrict]` attribute i received the message:

```
Could not execute service '', The following restrictions were not met: '\n -[External, Secure, HttpHead, HttpGet, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpOther, OneWay, Soap11, Soap12, Xml, Jsv, ProtoBuf, Csv, Html, Yaml, MsgPack, FormatOther, AnyEndpoint]'\n Unauthorized call was made from: Localhost, InSecure, HttpPost, Reply, Json
```

Can i change it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to change it for displaying it to user? or do you want to add extra information to this message?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling)?

Comment: i would like change the message displayed at a user...so i want customize the ResponseStatus when used: `[Restrict(EndpointAttributes.Secure | EndpointAttributes.External)]`

Comment: @mythz: Hi, I saw the guide "error handling" but unfortunately, I was not able to customize the `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception.
To overwrite the ResponseDto I wrote:                  `[Route("/page", "POST")]
 [SecureRequestFilterAttribute()]
    [Restrict(EndpointAttributes.Secure)]
    public class MyRequest : IReturn<MyResponse>
    {
    }
public class SecureRequestFilterAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
    {}`